# Nodes creation error in Ns2

Tags: protocols, nodes, ns2

I have implemented a new routing protocol named TRLR in ns-2.34. I am using fedora 13. I have modified ns-lib.tcl, ns-packet.tcl, priqueue.cc, packet.h, cmu-trace.{cc,h}. Then make clean, make and make install have completed successfully. Then I have tried to run this protocol using trlr_2.tcl and I got this strange error. I have no idea how to fix this error neither have I found an acceptable answer to this question anywhere. Please help me out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

```
[root@Care Desktop]# ns trlr_5.tcl 
num_nodes is set 5
warning: Please use -channel as shown in tcl/ex/wireless-mitf.tcl
INITIALIZE THE LIST xListHead

(_o17 cmd line 1)
    invoked from within
"_o17 cmd tracetarget _o31"
    invoked from within
"catch "$self cmd $args" ret"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {
set cls [$self info class]
global errorInfo
set savedInfo $errorInfo
error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
    (procedure "_o17" line 2)
    (SplitObject unknown line 2)
    invoked from within
"$ragent tracetarget $T"
   (procedure "_o14" line 14)
   (Node/MobileNode agenttrace line 14)
    invoked from within
"$node agenttrace $tracefd"
   (procedure "_o3" line 106)
   (Simulator create-wireless-node line 106)
    invoked from within
"_o3 create-wireless-node"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $self create-wireless-node $args"
    (procedure "_o3" line 23)
    (Simulator node line 23)
    invoked from within
"$ns_ node"
    ("for" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } {incr i} {
    set node_($i) [$ns_ node]   
    $node_($i) random-motion 0      ;# disable random motion
}"
(file "trlr_5.tcl" line 97)
```

Well after some googling around, I think this error is caused by my command() function in my trlr.h and trlr.cc files. So, I am attaching chunks of command function in those files here too.

<<< trlr.h >>>

```
#include <cmu-trace.h>
#include <agent.h>
#include <classifier/classifier-port.h>

class TRLR: public Agent 
{
private:
    routingTable rTable;
public:
    TRLR(nsaddr_t id);
    int  command(int, const char *const *);
protected:
    PortClassifier* dmux_;
    Trace* logtarget_;
    PriQueue* ifqueue;
};
```

<<< trlr.cc >>>

```
int TRLR::command(int argc, const char*const* argv) {
if(argc == 2) {
 Tcl& tcl = Tcl::instance();

if(strncasecmp(argv[1], "id", 2) == 0) {
  tcl.resultf("%d", index);
  return TCL_OK;
}

if(strncasecmp(argv[1], "start", 2) == 0) {
  rtimer.resched(0.0);
  return TCL_OK;
 }
}
else if(argc == 3) {
if(strcmp(argv[1], "index") == 0) {
  index = atoi(argv[2]);
  return TCL_OK;
}

else if (strcmp(argv[1], "port-dmux") == 0) {
    dmux_ = (PortClassifier *)TclObject::lookup(argv[2]);
if (dmux_ == 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "%s: %s lookup of %s failed\n", __FILE__,
    argv[1], argv[2]);
    return TCL_ERROR;
}
return TCL_OK;
}

else if(strcmp(argv[1], "if-queue") == 0) {
ifqueue = (PriQueue*) TclObject::lookup(argv[2]);      
  if(ifqueue == 0)
return TCL_ERROR;
  return TCL_OK;
}

else if (strcmp(argv[1], "log-target") == 0 || strcmp(argv[1], "tracetarget") == 0) {
    logtarget_ = (Trace*)TclObject::lookup(argv[2]);
if (logtarget_ == 0)
    return TCL_ERROR;
    return TCL_OK;
}
  }
return Agent::command(argc, argv);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added the lines (like trlr/trlr.o) in makefile before doing make?

Comment: Yes of course I have inserted these lines in Makefile. And Make was successful.

Comment: I have run 'make clean' and 'make', they are not giving any errors.